# json has error but get the data so can't be used

Tags: php, android, json, api

i make a api to my android app with php and if i call the api in browser it will get the data correctly but if i call it in android it will get some error

this is my api code

```
    <?php
$genre = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_GET['genre']);

  $query = mysqli_query($connection, 'SELECT user_review.*, data_movie.* FROM data_movie INNER JOIN user_review ON data_movie.id = user_review.id_movie WHERE genre LIKE "'. $genre .'%" order by created_at desc')
  or die(mysqli_error($connection));

  if (mysqli_num_rows($query) === 0) {
    responJson (['data' => []]);
  } else {
    $result = [];
    while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
      array_push($result, $data);
    }
    responJson(['data' =>
    $result]);
  }
     ?>
```

and this is what i get when i print what i called in android code

```
<br />
          <b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: genre in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\moviereview\route\get_review.php</b> on line <b>3</b><br />
          {"data":[{"id_movie":"7","id_review":"4","rating":"4","review":"menginspirasi","created_at":"2019-01-11 18:50:11","id_user":"1".......
```

when i call `localhost/moviereview/?action=get_review` and `localhost/moviereview/?action=get_review&genre=` it will parse all the data and when i call `localhost/moviereview/?action=get_review&genre=drama` it parse all drama data it's all ok in browser but when i implement in android it has error above and it don't have error only if i call it with genre data like drama on my example.
why this is happend please help

Comment: maybe u need to add alias with `genre`

Comment: yes it ok when i add genre alias but it also ok when i not add it if it in browser like my example above @devpro

Answer (score 0):

Just close error display on screen and json parsing problem will go away. 
try this after php open tag.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 0);
```

Although you will not solve the actual root of the problem, but since it is a notice you can leave with it instead of having a non working service.